# Perceptron in C fails to train

Tags: c, neural-network

Trying to implement a perceptron in C, can't get it to train.
The output always just goes to zero and I don't know what’s wrong.
Although, I do suspect it might be either the delta function or me just incorrectly implementing the perceptron.

Thanks in advance to everyone who helps!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define arrayLength(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

int main(){
    float trainInputs [2][2] = {{0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
    float trainOutputs [2][1] = {{1.0f}, {0.0f}};
    int amontOfTrainData = 1;

    float inputs [] = {0.0f, 1.1f};
    float outputs [] = {0.0f};
    float wights [(arrayLength(inputs) * arrayLength(outputs))] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};
    float learningRate = 0.01f;

    float delta(float actual, float want, float wight){
        float error = want - actual;
        float out = error * learningRate * wight;
        printf(":%.6f:\n", out);
        return out;
    }

    // Run perceptron

    void run(bool train){
        int outputInc = 0;
        int wightInc = 0;
        while(outputInc < arrayLength(outputs)){
            int inputInc = 0;

            while(inputInc < arrayLength(inputs)){
                if(train){
                    int x = 0;
                    while(x < amontOfTrainData){
                        outputs[outputInc] = trainInputs[x][inputInc] * wights[wightInc];
                        wights[wightInc] = delta(outputs[outputInc], trainOutputs[x][outputInc], wights[wightInc]);
                        x++;
                    }
                }else{
                    outputs[outputInc] = inputs[inputInc] * wights[wightInc];
                }
                inputInc++;
                wightInc++;
            }
            //printf("out[%i]: %.5f\n", outputInc, outputs[outputInc]);
            outputInc++;
        }
    }

    int b = 0;
    while(b < 100){
        run(true);
        b++;
    }
    printf("-----------[ 100 LOOPS DONE ]-----------\n");
    run(false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef int bool;` => please use standard, include `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: The length of this array is 2, but you provide 4 initializers: `float wights [(arrayLength(inputs) * arrayLength(outputs))] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};`

Comment: Note that nested function definitions are not allowed in C, though there is a gcc extension which allows it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `error`, `learningRate` and `wight` are less than 0, the expression `error * learningRate * wight` will tend to 0 too.

The `delta` should not be the new value for the weight, it is the amount of change, so instead of:

```
wights[wightInc] = delta(...);
```

Try:

```
wights[wightInc] += delta(...);
```

(Which source are you using for you perceptron formulas?)

Answer (score 1):

I have applied all the changes and this is the final working code.
Thanks to everyone who helped me!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define arrayLength(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

float trainInputs [2][2] = {{0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
float trainOutputs [2][1] = {{1.0f}, {0.0f}};
int amontOfTrainData = 1;

float inputs [] = {1.0f, 1.0f};
float outputs [] = {0.0f};
float wights [(arrayLength(inputs) * arrayLength(outputs))] = {0.001f, 0.001f};
float learningRate = 0.1f;


float delta(float actual, float want, float wight)
{
    float error = want - actual;
    float out = error * learningRate * wight;
    return out;
}

void run(bool train)
{
    int outputInc = 0;
    int wightInc = 0;
    while(outputInc < arrayLength(outputs))
    {
        int inputInc = 0;

        while(inputInc < arrayLength(inputs))
        {
            if(train)
            {
                int x = 0;
                while(x < amontOfTrainData)
                {
                    outputs[outputInc] = trainInputs[x][inputInc] * wights[wightInc];
                    wights[wightInc] += delta(outputs[outputInc], trainOutputs[x][outputInc], wights[wightInc]);
                    x++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                outputs[outputInc] = inputs[inputInc] * wights[wightInc];
            }
            inputInc++;
            wightInc++;
        }
        printf("out[%i]: %.5f\n", outputInc, outputs[outputInc]);
        outputInc++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Run neural network
    int b = 0;
    int loops = 500;
    while(b < loops)
    {
        run(true);
        b++;
    }
    printf("-----------[ %i LOOPS DONE ]-----------\n", loops);
    run(false);

    return 0;
}
```